# How to copy only the newest sub directory to a destination linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell, copy, cp, suse

I have a parent folder where every day a new subdirectory is automatically created.  The subdirectory naming format is '2013-10-02T1430+0000'.  Later on today the new subdirectory created will be named ''2013-10-03T1430+0000'.

I need a script which will on a schedule automatically copy only the contents of the latest subdirectory created to another folder.

I have the cp command down ok but I need to somehow subsitute in the cp source the latest subdirectory name.  After doing some research I found the following command will return the latest or newest subdirectory:

```
ls -tr ParentFolder | tail -1
```

How do I get the result of this command to be placed into the cp command?  Is there an easier way of doing this?

Many thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To save the result of a command you can use the `var=$(command)` expression.

In your case,

```
last_dir=$(ls -tr ParentFolder | tail -1)
```

So then you can `cp $last_dir /another/path`, etc.

Note by the way that parsing `ls` [is not very optimal](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), so if you know that the dir name will always have today's date, you can get it with the `date` command:

```
$ date
Thu Oct  3 11:02:28 CEST 2013
```

And its options:

```
$ date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%z"
2013-10-03T1108+0200
```

Comment: Since the directory names are without space and the only processing on the ls is `tail`, probably this is not so bad. Interesting link though. Just for completeness, this could also be done inline: `cp $(ls -tr ParentFolder | tail -1) /another/path`. I would still prefer the variable though.

Comment: Normally they mention `ls` parsing as devil thing to do, although you are right that in this case can be harmless. I also prefer the variable, as per new users it is much clearer than one-liners. Thanks for commenting!

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  All of these options seem to do the trick.  How much more work would be involved to log to a log file the success or failure of this copy?

Comment: How much more work would be involved to log to a log file the success or failure of this copy operation?  I've made the tick green now.

Comment: After the `cp` you can `echo $?`. In case it is 0, it means it was successful. Otherwise there was an error.